# How to force print quotes in a yaml file generated using python?

Tags: python, yaml

I am reading values from an excel using python and generating a yaml file using `yaml.safe_dumps`.

Issue - i want a value to be displayed in a single quote in the yaml file. Eg : `'test'`.

i have tried a couple of options, i either get the output as `'''test'''` or `test` or `!python/unicode 'test'`

Any idea how i can get the single quotes to display in the yaml file.

Here is the complete code:

```
import yaml

class RDF:
   def __init__(self):
      self.test = "test"

   def create_TDF(self):
      tdf_file_names_new_list = {}
      tdf_file_names_new_list['ID'] = ""
      tdf_file_names_new_list['name'] = ""
      varname = 'test'
      test_name = 'test1'
      test_type = 'single'
      test_definition_data = dict(
        testName = "",
        innerFilterName = 'inner filter',
        testType  = "",
        analysisType = "",
        testInformation = {})

      test_definition_data['testInformation']['p']={}
      p_dict={}
      p_dict['VarName'] = varname
      p_dict['VFile'] = 'file'
      p_dict['affected'] = 'T'
      test_definition_data['testInformation']['p'] = p_dict


      test_definition_data['testInformation']['m']={}
      test_definition_data['testInformation']['m']['VarName']=varname

      test_definition_data['analysisType'] = 'T'
      test_definition_data['testName'] = test_name
      # The "testType" value is what i want to display in "single quotes".
      # tried str(row[3].value) -> output still does not display single quotes.
      # if i change "yaml.safe_dump" statement below to ---> tdf_yaml_file.write(yaml.dump(test_definition_data)) then the output is ---> testType: !!python/unicode 'Hypotonia'


      test_definition_data['testType'] = test_type

      with open('TDF_1'+'.tdf',"w") as tdf_yaml_file:
          tdf_yaml_file.write(yaml.safe_dump(test_definition_data,encoding='utf-8', allow_unicode=False))
        #tdf_yaml_file.write(yaml.dump(test_definition_data))
      tdf_yaml_file.close()


def main():
    tdf = RDF()
    tdf.create_TDF()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Please modify your code sample to work standing alone, and show your work -- for instance, for the outputs you're actually getting, show which input corresponded to each.

Comment: That said -- while it's the yaml module's job to be able to serialize all possible YAML values (within documented constraints), it *isn't* its job to be able to serialize them to specific representations. If the representation it chooses deserializes to the original value, the serializer has done its job, whether or not that representation looks the way you want it to.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - i have added code. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't ask for your original code; rather, I asked for a sample sufficient to operate standalone. See http://sscce.org/ or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for discussion on how to build a minimal, complete, verifiable example (or a short, self-contained, correct example in SSCCE terminology).

Comment: Also, since this doesn't include `Test.xlsx`, it's **still** not sufficient to operate standalone (thus, it isn't verifiable in MCVE terms, or isn't self-contained in SSCCE terms). You'd do better to take out the Excel-reading components altogether, and hardcode only enough data to demonstrate the bug.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - hi, Updated code to operate standalone.

Comment: This is still anything but minimal (in MCVE terms) or short (in SSCCE terms). Why is it tens of lines rather than two or three?

Comment: Literally, the following one line would suffice to demonstrate your problem clearly and succinctly: `for s in ['yaml', '"yaml"', "'yaml'"]: print yaml.safe_dump(s)`.

Comment: (This is much like complaining that some specific XML library will only write an element as `<foo bar="val1" baz="val2"/>`, when you want `<foo baz="val2" bar="val1"/>`; I can't see anything but getting laughed out of the room for that request either, when not made in the service of supporting a standardized canonical form of the syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The forms emitted by PyYAML are **entirely semantically equivalent** to the output you're requesting. PyYAML makes no promises (nor can any equivalent library reasonably expect to make promises) to support every possible semantically equivalent serialization.

That is to say:

```
yaml.safe_load('yaml') == yaml.safe_load("'yaml'")
```

...is a truthy statement, so any YAML parser that treats `yaml` and `'yaml'` differently is buggy; you should report such bugs as you're seeing to that parser's maintainers.

---

It's noteworthy that many on-disk formats do specify and support a well-defined canonical form. YAML's specification has a partial definition of this, and PyYAML supports it as an output format. However, this format is *not* equivalent to what you're requesting:

```
>>> print yaml.safe_dump('yaml', canonical=True)
---
!!str "yaml"
```